# Phalcon Framework: Can't save not required strings in database

Tags: validation, save, required, string, phalcon

I'm using the Phalcon framework for PHP, and I would like to save my form into the database, all is working how is supposed to, but I can't save empty strings in some (not required) fields.

How can I save not required field? Every time I save not required fields without input, I get an error like "lastname field is required.".

Anyone?

Sorry, my English is not good, I'm learning...

---

My controller code is:

```
$this->view->disable();
$usuario = new Usuarios();

    $usuario->usuario = $this->request->getPost("usuario");
    $usuario->email = $this->request->getPost("email");
    $usuario->senha = $this->request->getPost("senha");
    $usuario->nome = $this->request->getPost("nome");
    $usuario->sobrenome = $this->request->getPost("sobrenome");
    $usuario->icone = $this->request->getPost("icone");
    $usuario->fixo = $this->request->getPost("fixo");
    $usuario->celular = $this->request->getPost("celular");
    $usuario->tipo = $this->request->getPost("tipo");

    $usuario->save();
```

And I have basic validations in my model...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can choose one of the these solution which suggested on 
[How to make models use defaults in Phalcon PHP Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15951959/how-to-make-models-use-defaults-in-phalcon-php-framework)

Last and simple solution:

```
$usuario->usuario = $this->request->getPost("usuario") || "";
```

Comment: I found a solution, disabling the Phalcon default empty field validation, and inserting all required fields directly in the model validation function. I didnt test your solution, but that is nice, I'll remember to use || ""; next time! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Late answer, but maybe it will be useful for someone. If you want phalcon to ignore specific fields you need to use `skipAttributes()`:

**Example:**

```
class Usuarios extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{
    public function initialize()
    {
    $this->skipAttributes(array('field1', 'field2'));
    }
}
```

Here is a link to the documentation: http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html#skipping-columns

Comment: Thank you for your contribution! I already solved this issue but it may help someone else with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you wand to save an empty string for some fields (one of reasons of such an error like "lastname field is required"), you can use Phalcon Model allowEmptyStringValues method:

```
class Robots extends Model
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->allowEmptyStringValues(['usuario', 'someelse', 'someother']);
    }
}
```

for allowing empty strings saving for manually listed fields.

Also check your Usuarios model (it have field named "lastname") and your database structure NULL / NOT NULL field attributes.

Answer (score 0):

It might be failing because you're trying to save NULL instead of an empty string. I unfortunately can't reply as a comment because of the reputation requirement, but could you post the contents of your Usuarios model? I need to see what your validations look like.